# Finding eigenvalues of a block matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

Suppose $A\in M_n(C)$ and define $B = \begin{pmatrix}O & A\\ A & 2A\end{pmatrix}$. Find eigenvalues of $B$ in terms of $A$.

I know that to find eigenvalues of $B$ we have to solve $det(B-xI)=0$. Also, $B$ has square blocks of the same order so based on [Determinant of Block matrices:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices)  $det \begin{pmatrix}-xI & A\\A & 2A-xI\end{pmatrix}= det((-xI)(2A-xI) -A^2)$.

But I don't know how to solve the equation.

Comment: can you factorize the quadratic formula in the determinant? (write it as $det(A-yI)det(A-zI)$)

Comment: Please not that in general $\det\begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{bmatrix} \neq \det(AD - BC)$. It holds here since the 1,1 block is mutiple of $I$. I am not sure if you really ment it like this but the parenthesis suggest that a bit so I am leaving this here for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

The quick approach is to simply note that $B$ is the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) $B = M \otimes A$, where
$$
M = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&2}.
$$
Because the eigenvalues of $M$ are $1 \pm \sqrt{2}$, the properties of the Kronecker product imply that the eigenvalues of $B$ will be of the form $\lambda (1 \pm \sqrt{2})$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$.

Alternatively, we can continue your approach to note that
$$
\det(M - xI) = \det(-xI(2A-xI) -A^2) = \det(x^2 I - 2x A - A^2)\\
= \det([xI - (1 - \sqrt{2})A][xI - (1 + \sqrt{2})A]).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $(V_k,\lambda_k$) be the eigenpairs of $A$, meaning that:

$$AV_k=\lambda_kV_k\tag{1}$$

Let us look for eigenvectors of $B$ under the following form:

$$\begin{pmatrix}O & A\\ A & 2A\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}V_k\\ aV_k\end{pmatrix}=\mu_k\begin{pmatrix}V_k\\ aV_k\end{pmatrix}$$

which is equivalent (due to (1)) to the fact that:

$$\begin{cases} a\lambda_kV_k&=&\mu_kV_k\\
 (1+2a)\lambda_kV_k&=&a\mu_kV_k\end{cases} \ \implies \ \begin{cases} a\lambda &=&\mu_k\\
 (1+2a)\lambda_k&=&a\mu_k\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

therefore, we have the proportionnality:

$$\dfrac{1+2a}{a}=a$$

a quadratic equation with roots $a'=1-\sqrt{2}$ and $a''=1+\sqrt{2}$.

Therefore, using the fact that $a\lambda_k=\mu_k$, the $a'\lambda_k$ and the $a''\lambda_k$ are eigenvalues with specific eigenvectors.

As $B$ is a $2n \times 2n$ matrix, we have thus found all of them.

Remark: The idea to look for eigenvectors having the given form comes from the habit to work on the Kronecker form as in the solution given by @Ben Grossmann.

Comment: @Korf Thank you very much.